# Accessing multiple services using single url docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose, microservices

I am using docker-compose to deploy multiple microservices in flask. Here is the compose code

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-api:
    volumes:
      - ./test-api:/test-api
    build: test-api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  search:
    volumes:
      - ./seach:/search
    environment:
      - HTTP_PORT=5000
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    build: search
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    link:
      - redis
```

Now I have to access this service from single URL eg: `http://example.com/test-api` or `http://example.com/search`, but I am unable to figure it out since the 2 services are running are on 2 different ports. I know I need to use nginx and configure it so that I can access them. But I am not sure how to do that. Can someone help me with this or at least give me some docs to read so as to understand the routing?

Also both the services use /health to report the result of health-check. How do I access the health check for both the services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the people who are looking for a quick solution, here is my nginx file

```
http {


    server {

        listen 80;

        location /test {
            proxy_pass http://test-api:5000;
        }
        location /search {
            proxy_pass http://search:5000;
        }
        location /health-test {
            proxy_pass http://test-api:5000/health;
        }
        location /health-search {
            proxy_pass http://search:5000/health;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote you should use a load balancer placed in front of your services. Now, you should create a docker network without exposing ports. the only container that exposes ports should be the nginx container in order to handle all clients request. The `test-api`, `search` and `nginx` should be part of the same docker network in order to allow nginx to dispatch the request to the right container. Your `docker-compose` file should look like this:

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      loadbalancer:
        image: nginx
      ports:
       - "80:8080"
      networks:
        - my_netowrk
      test-api:
        volumes:
          - ./test-api:/test-api
        build: test-api
        networks:
         - my_netowrk

      redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        networks:
          - my_netowrk

      search:
        volumes:
          - ./seach:/search
        environment:
          - HTTP_PORT=5000
          - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
        build: search
        networks:
         - my_netowrk

   networks:
     my_netowrk:
       driver: <driver>
```

I would advise you to don't use `links` anymore, they are old and deprecated.
You can learn more about `docker networks` from links below:

- https://docs.docker.com/network/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference

Comment: Hi @Giorgio I am able to use docker network to talk between the containers, but still unable to route requests to the specific container based on the URL. Second thing is, I have health-check for both the services. How can I access the /health url on both services?

Comment: This should be nginx config related. You have to create one `proxy_pass` rule for each service that you want to communicate with. Docker allows you to communicate with ache container already connected to the same network using just the service's name. This [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-setup-NGINX-to-proxy-different-paths-on-the-the-same-domain-to-different-back-end-apps-or-services) may help you to achieve that.